# Wildfly Server Not Connected but started then Timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I got an issue with my environment I guess.

I use `Eclipse Photon` and `WildFly 11` for `Maven Projects`.

The issue is when I start my WildFly server on Eclipse. I wait few seconds then I have the following message :

> 19:46:06,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 24044ms - Started 674 of 900 services (355 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

But my server seems to not work correctly. I'll explain:

After I start the server and the message is displayed, I can access to `localhost:8080/myproject` but, when the timeout setting to start server is reach (450 seconds by default) the server stops. Like it wasn't fully started.

Furthermore, if I go to -> `Servers` -> `WildFly 11` -> `Server Details`, I see the mention Not Connected and nothing else while I should get some folder like Attributes, Core Services, Deployments, etc.

I tried reinstall Eclipse, WildFly 11 and 13, and I tried with project in the server and with an empty server, with a new workspace... The issue is still there.

Has anyone ever had this concern or has any leads to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried starting your WildFly instance from the command line first? I say this because I've downloaded Eclipse Photon (*Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Photon Release (4.8.0), Build id: 20180619-1200*), WildFly 11 and WildFly 13, created two new Server instances on Eclipse, started them and, in both cases, everything is okay.

Comment: It's seems to start, I have got all infos from the command line but it doens't really solve my issue because I steel dont have infos on my Eclipse. I think it can be either because Eclipse can't listen echo from fully started WildFly Server and then because he didn't get this, it kills the server. By the way, I believe you, I install all my setup (WildFly, Eclipse and the project on the PC of a friend, the same setup I used and it worked fine...

Comment: Are you sure, that your application deployed without errors? (e.g. check for .failed files in /standalone/deployment folder) Other than that, is it a vanilla WildFly installation or did you configure something in standalone.xml which could cause a startup timeout?

Comment: @AlexanderRühl +1 for alerting the OP on deployment errors. Nevertheless, I believe the OP tried to start the server without any application being deploy and the behaviour was the same: _...and I tried with project in the server and with an empty server, with a new workspace... The issue is still there._. Do you think it's possible that the OP removed the application from the server but the _.deployed_ application folder was left there?

Comment: @aribeiro: Mmm, might be possible, still I don't see why the server should terminate iteself then.